# tengo un problema con el Goto ficheros lotes

Tags: windows, cmd, batch, .bat, echo

hola buenas noches tengo un problema con este codigo creo que el error es en el Goto pero no estoy muy seguro lo que intento es copiar el fichero recibido como segundo parámetro con el nombre indicado como primer parámetro, si alguien es tan amable de hecharme la mano.

```
@echo off
color 4e
copy %1 %2
goto nivel0
:nivel1
echo El fichero %1 no ha podido ser 
copiado goto FIN
:nivel0
echo El fichero %1 ha sido copiado con el nombre %2
:FIN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el script dice que recibirá el archivo indicado como 1er parámetro %1 y lo copiará donde diga el 2da parámetro %2

Ej: `file.bat C:\Foto.jpg "C:\Mis Imagenes\Imagen.jpg"`

Debes tener en cuenta:

1. La dirección o nombre del archivo, debe llevar `"` si tiene espacios en el nombre/s del archivo o carpeta/s.
2. El nombre del archivo debe colocarse también en el 2do parámetro.
3. Añadir las condiciones para hacer uso de la respuesta de `copy %1 %2` y poder mostrar correctamente el resultado.

Comment: Gracias hermano!! :)